# Numbering issue in \printbiblography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

i am using biblatex for including publications in my resume. I am using following code

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[bibstyle=publist,boldyear=true,plauthorhandling=highlight,sorting=ymdnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{Section}{Publications}
\nocite{aip1,aip2,cmsim,chaos12,ncose1,ncose2,ncose3,pedes18,iccare19,ijrte19}
\printbibliography[type=article,title={\large{Journal Papers}}]
\printbibliography[type=inproceedings,title={\large{Conference Papers}}]
\end{Section}
\end{document}
```

the problem I am facing is of continuous numbering for publications.

[image]

I want numbering for conference to start from 1. What should I do?

Comment: The code as posted in the question can not be compiled because it does not state the document class and does not define the used sorting scheme. We also don't have your `.bib` file. Please always try to compile the code you post as a minimal example in a new, empty document in a new, empty folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to add `resetnumbers` to your `\printbibliography`s to restart the numbering. If you use `resetnumbers` you must also set `defernumbers=true,` globally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[bibstyle=publist,
  boldyear=true, plauthorhandling=highlight,
  defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{sigfridsson,aksin,yoon,moraux,salam}
\printbibliography[resetnumbers, type=article, title={Journal Papers}]
\printbibliography[resetnumbers, type=inproceedings, title={Conference Papers}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Two bibliographies starting at 1.]

Note that you may have to delete the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) if you add or remove the `defernumbers` option.

Comment: It works like a charm !! Thank you !!

Comment: @BhooshanRajpathak If the answer helped you, you may want to consider accepting it by clicking on the green checkmark on the top left. That way the question is marked as resolved. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.